# get username and password from a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, model-view-controller

I have code as stated bellow for finding user that has the same username and password using a list.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
          
          List<Korisnik> korisnici = (List<Korisnik>)HttpContext.Application["korisnici"];

          Korisnik user = korisnici.Find(u => u.KorisnickoIme.Equals(username) && u.Lozinka.Equals(password));
           

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = $"User with credentials does not exist!";
                return View("Index");
            }

            Session["korisnici"] = user;
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I would like to do it the same but for a Dictionary. I don't know how to find a person with the same password and username like I did for the list. The dictionary key is the username. The code should look something like this :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
        {
          
          Dictionary<string, Korisnik> korisnici = (Dictionary<string, Korisnik>)HttpContext.Application["korisnici"];

         // code where i find the requested stuff

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = $"User with credentials does not exist!";
                return View("Index");
            }

            Session["korisnici"] = user;
            
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: What should the key be? Probably username as that is always unique? So use that as the key in the dictionary. When you get the record then check if the password is the same in the found record.

Comment: On a side note I am going to assume that you are not going to store passwords in plain text in a production app and that this app is being built for school or some learning purpose. If you do ever have to work on anything "real" (where it will be used by anyone other than you) then you need to change the code to *never store passwords in plain text*. If this is something for external use then consider asp.net identity or any other off the shelf toolkits that you can integrate into your app.

Comment: The key is username and it is always unique. Yes this is for learning purpose and I'm practicing like this for now, thank you for your advice :')

Comment: Do remember to create your `Dictionary<string,Korisnik>` instance by passing an appropriate [`StringComparer.XXX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-5.0) value, which one depends on the character set allowed and how you want characters handled. Generally you would probably use [`OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=net-5.0) as user names are *usually* not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways a Dictionary might be able to help here, and I would point out ContainsKey, which you can use to check for the username. Finding that username's password from the dictionary is as easy as using myDictionary["key"].

If the username is 'Foo', you could write

```
if (korisnici.ContainsKey("Foo"))  
{  
    var password = korisnici["Foo"];  
}
```

Agree with the comments, though, plaintext passwords don't feel great.